# How to adjust Portrait oriented Image to Landscape orientation using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

I got ploblem with image display like whenever i am trying to show portrait oriented image in landscape orientation then image is auto rotating to left 90 degree.

Comment: what do you think is causing this? do you have some javascript that does it?

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX for your response,No i don't have any code for that.My display image resolution is 150(width) X 100(height).For this resolution Portrait images are automatically rotating.So can you give me any solution for that.

Comment: no solution, because that just doesn't happen